# Why doesn't knex create serial column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I use knex to create a postgres table as following:

```
knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.bigIncrements('user_id');
    ....
})
```

But after the table was created, the column `user_id` is a `integer` not the `serial` as expected.

The sql get by the pgAdmin is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    user_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass),
    ....
)
```

And the consequence is that when I do `insert` statement, the `user_id` won't auto increment as expected.

Any gives?

====================

Currently I just changed to mysql connection, and the inserting works well. But if I changed the database back to postgresql, then inserting would fail due to the duplication of user_id. The code can be found here:  https://github.com/buzz-buzz/buzz-service

Answer (score 3):

`serial` and `bigserial` are not real types they are just shorthand for what pgAdmin is showing.

You will also find that a sequence has been created with the name `users_user_id_seq` when you look under sequences in pgAdmin.

Comment: What should I do to let the postgresql auto increments the user_id when I do inserting? I changed the connection string to mysql the inserting would be fine, but if I changed back to postgresql then inserting would be fail due to the duplication of user_id.  The code can be found here: https://github.com/buzz-buzz/buzz-service

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question, I and many other will not be going to dig through your repository to find the problem. Also I'm not familiar with knex.js only with postgresql. However make sure not to try to insert an actual value for user_id. Either the column shouldn't be included in the INSERT statement or DEFAULT should be passed as it's value.

Comment: Note that when you have inserted actual values directly into the user_id column the sequence will not know this and might generate values you have inserted previously resulting in the same error. Check in pgAdmin that the current value of the sequence is higher then the highest is in your table.